# Javascript: how to run timer at every "ROUND" x seconds?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to run my **javascript** timer in every 5 seconds, but only then, when the current time is at *"round"* 5 seconds (I mean when the second value is divisible by 5.) So, I want to set the start time to *"round"* 5 seconds.

Not good, when the second is (for example): 7, 12, 17, 22 etc ...

Good: 0, 5, 10, 15 etc ...

My current code (runs well in every 5 seconds, but the start is not set to *"round"* 5 seconds):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.setInterval(function(){
        draw();
        }, 5000);
</script>
```

Please, help me.

Comment: Synced to what baseline? The user's local clock's seconds? (which may not be accurate, keep in mind) Or something else, like time since pageload, or the server's time?

Comment: Current GMT is the time

Comment: According to who? The user's local clock, or the server (or an external time API)?

Comment: The timezone should be egal because we only want the seconds and not the hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the actual date and extract seconds*1000 and milliseconds. Modulo 5.000 gets ms from last 5s interval subtract this from 5.000 and you get the first start.
Start the first time with `setTimeout` and after this every 5.000 ms with `setInterval`.

```js
let date = new Date();
let ms = date.getSeconds()*1000 + date.getMilliseconds();
let start = 5000 - (ms %5000);
//console.log(ms, start);

setTimeout(function(){
    doIt();
    window.setInterval(doIt, 5000); 
}, start);

function doIt() {
    console.log('Boom');
}
```

Comment: CertainPerformance and Sascha: your codes gives exactly the result what I want. I will apply one of them tomorrow. Is it possible to accept 2 answers?

Comment: No is it not. If you have earned 15 reputation then you can upvote as many answers and questions as you want but accepting answers is only 1 possible. If you change it afterwards you toggle it between both.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a loop every 1 sec, to check if `modulus of getUTCMinutes() / 5 == 0`, and once it does, then execute your script.. so it will START at that 5 min mark, and then continue on it's own..

Comment: Code example would be nice, I am not expert in javascript

Comment: and we are not here to do the work for you.. but rather help you in your code errors. If you try to research this yourself you will learn way more, than a ready code example...

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive `setTimeout`s instead, which measures the time between now and the next "round" seconds number:

```js
const scheduleDraw = () => {
  const now = new Date();
  const secondsToNext = 5 - (now.getSeconds() % 5);
  const millisecondsToNext = ((secondsToNext - 1) * 1000) + (1000 - now.getMilliseconds());
  setTimeout(draw, millisecondsToNext);
};
const draw = () => {
  console.log('drawing at', new Date());
  scheduleDraw();
};
scheduleDraw();
```

Don't use `setInterval` - it'll get inaccurate after a while, especially if the user switches browser tabs. Better to calculate the new timeout every time.

Comment: CertainPerformance and Sascha: your codes gives exactly the result what I want. I will apply one of them tomorrow. Is it possible to accept 2 answers?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have a function that reads out the system time, and determines how much time is left for the next 5 second moment, and triggers a corresponding `setTimeout` for that.

You should allow for a few milliseconds of variation though:

```js
function callAt5(callback) {
    let now = new Date();
    let milli = (now.getMilliseconds() + 1000 * now.getSeconds()) % 5000;
    setTimeout(callAt5.bind(null, callback), 5000 - milli);
    if (milli < 100) callback();
}

// pass the callback which you want to execute at each 5 second mark:
callAt5(() => console.log(new Date));
```

Comment: Thank you trincot, but I got 14, 19, 24 etc ... which is not exactly what I need for

Comment: Look at the decimals with milliseconds. That is just 5 milliseconds away from the 5 mark. If you prefer to be some milliseconds too *late* than too *early*, then remove the `+ 10` in the code. I just did that now. So now the call will be made a few milliseconds *after* the 5 second mark.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Guys, now I have 3 good solutions. Can I mark all the 3 as accepted?

Comment: No you can't. Only one answer can be marked. Later when you have more reputation, you can give votes to multiple answers you like.

Comment: Just to explain my first version of the code: I attempted to be **as close as possible** to the 5 second mark. But now I understand you want to never have it *before* the 5 second mark, so now the error margin will be greater, as it now always comes some milliseconds *after* the 5 second mark.